# Methods to classify observed data into states

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, time-series

Given a time series (that sometimes unpredictably alternates between random and non-random and is not stationary). What mathematical methods are there to *classify the observed set of data into different states*?

I have tried classifying the data into states by its empirical distribution for a given period, but find that it is very dependent on parameters such as sample length and bin-size (in histogram). Are there any better methods?

Any suggestions very welcome!

Edit: preferably analytical methods, i.e. no tools such as machine learning

Edit2: The time series has 3 values for each day. (Analogous to measuring temperature but it has no unit). The TS is about 30000 days long (so a 30000x3 matrix). For every day we are given the "temperature" measured at the same time "every day at 12:00", and the highest- / lowest "temperature" value respectively for that same day. My goal is to divide the TS into different states to better visualize the process, maybe find probabilities of going from one state to another (eg. Markov process), and find states that do not communicate etc.

[Link to sample of 5000 data points.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sa6e4x84vxm6qpi/daily_data_5000_2.csv?dl=0) First column is daily max value, second column is daily minimum value, third is daily measurement at 12:00 and I also added a fourth column (from second csv-file) which is the daily number of observations.

Comment: Do you know what the states are? What features of the data are you trying to pick out? This could turn into a very interesting question, but we definitely need a fair bit more context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That is the thing, I don't know how many states there are. I could guess and say that at least 2 (bcs it goes up and down), but this would be very unscientific. I would like to isolate any behavior specific to parts of the data (maybe with descriptive statistics like mean or variance, but something more sensitive and not so easily fooled to capture the behavior).

Comment: So I would say you need to take a step back and ask bigger questions. What is the context of this time series? What are the variables? What's your sampling rate? How many channels? What, ultimately, are you trying to do here?

Comment: Ok. The time series has 3 values for each day. (Analogous to measuring temperature but it has no unit). The TS is about 30000 days long (so a 30000x3 matrix). For every day we are given the "temperature" measured at the same time "every day at 12:00", and the highest- / lowest "temperature" value respectively for that same day.

Comment: Ok, that's a start. And what do you want to do with these temperatures?

Comment: My goal is to divide the TS into different states and then maybe be able to convert it into a markov process, to predict probability of going from one state into another, and maybe find states that do not communicate etc. To better visualize the process

Comment: If you don't know what the "states" are in advance, then that sounds like you get to pick them. You could think about increasing or decreasing. To detect that, you can fit slopes to consecutive groups of points.

Comment: I would suggest wavelet decomposition and short-time Fourier transform. One big difficulty will likely be to isolate the trend from the noise. There is a rather large literature on trend detection (useful in finance, economics, chemical industry...). It's also similar to seasonal adjustment (decomposition in noise-cycle-trend).

Comment: @AdrianKeister do you mean to divide into different states depending on the angle of the slope for a certain time period?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut with trend detection, wont that lead to things like machine learning and pattern recognition? (I was hoping to do a more analytical approach by treating the system like a deterministic chaotic system)

Comment: You have to decide what the states are in a way that means something to you. I can't do that for you - nobody can. There are all kinds of things you can look for in a time series (increasing/decreasing, peaks, valleys, etc.). They only mean something in the context of your problem.

Comment: @AdrianKeister okay, thanks! are there some mathematical methods you would recommend that I read up on? Or could you maybe give an answer with outline how you would tackle the problem theoretically?

Comment: It could, but when I did an internship on this in 2004, machine learning was not yet hype, and it involved more "classical" time series methods (filters, Fourier transform, wavelets). Nowadays it might be approached by other means as you suggest.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut hmm, I saw in your profile that you have a lot of trigonometry tags, do you think there are any trigonometric methods to classify data? Areas, ratios, angles, anything?

Comment: @litmus: Honestly, I would go with the basics of fitting lines to points (technically, that's actually a machine learning task; depending on how broadly you define ML, *all* of this could be ML!), and finding peaks. That'll certainly get you started. There are libraries in many programming languages to do this.

Comment: Any measure is good, as long as you find the way to extract the useful data: slopes are very sensitive to noise for instance (a derivative is roughly equivalent to a high pass filter), area less so (equivalent to a low-pass filter), but area does not measure a trend. You have to consider several problems here: remove noise (could be done with wathelet smoothing), and what kind of measure can discriminate your events of interest. In the applications I considered, the final measure was a quadratic form computed from several smoothed datapoints (roughly a variance).

Comment: @AdrianKeister Ok, thanks for the idea, I shall read up on that!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks, I shall also read up on that!

Comment: I have added a link to a 5000 sample if anyone of you want to give a swing at it